# ruby code, what is the code error below as shown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Error message I get:
undefined local variable or method `rev` for #

What is wrong with my if/else statement for the numbers method?
Thank you for your help

This is my code:

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  if rev
    arr.sort!{|item1, item2| item2<=>item1}
  else
    arr.sort!{|item1, item2| item1<=>item2}
  end
end

puts Array

numbers=[10, 12, 35, 17]
numbers.sort!
if rev == true
  numbers.reverse! {|item1, item2, item3, item4|}
else
  rev == false
  puts numbers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are defining `alphabetize` but you are not calling it. 
the error that you are having "undefined local variable or method rev" is because rev is not set  in your console you can do

```
def alphabetize(arr, rev=false)
  if rev
    arr.sort!{|item1, item2| item2<=>item1}
  else
    arr.sort!{|item1, item2| item1<=>item2}
  end
end

numbers=[10, 12, 35, 17]
alphabetize(numbers, false) # [10, 12, 17, 35]
alphabetize(numbers, true)  # [35, 17, 12, 10]
```

now for the second part you can do it like this

```
numbers=[10, 12, 35, 17]
rev = true # you are missing this line 
if rev == true
  numbers.reverse! {|item1, item2, item3, item4|}
else
  rev == false
  puts numbers
end
```

Comment: Thank you MZaragoza! that helps a lot:)